# Permission Denied when Installing Packages

Tags: r

I am trying to install a package from github which requires me to update several other packages.
I keep running into the same error with different package updates:

```r
Warning message:
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying D:\OfirL1\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to D:\OfirL1\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
```

I tried reinstalling manually, but the same error occurs. Tried from a vanilla session of R.
I went to the `win-library\3.6` directory but there is no `00LOCK` folder there at all, so I can't figure out what causes this issue.

Comment: maybe check your task manager to make sure that there are no other R session running.

Comment: Also, make sure you have write permissions.

Comment: clean your pkg directory as noted in the linked dup, then install rlang, then install everything else.

Comment: @HongOoi I followed your link. There were no zero-length files in my `3.6` I manually deleted the `rlang` file, restarted R and installed it again and it worked, but then the same error appeared on another package. I'd like to know what causes the problem, as there is no `00LOCK` folder. Manually deleting folders every time couldn't possibly be a long-term solution.